# ES6 - Parse HTML string to Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an HTML formatted string:

```js
let dataString = '<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure> <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>';
```

How can I parse this string to get an array of tags as below?

```js
let dataArray = [
  '<p>Lorem ipsum</p>',
  '<figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>',
  '<p>Lorem ipsum 2</p>',
  '<figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>',
];
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: What have you tried yet? It's better to showcase what you have tried so people can have a better understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could create a DOM element, set the innerHTML to this string and get the element's child nodes.

Comment: I tried .split(/<p>/g) but it only split <p> tags. I want to have <figure>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn it into a document with `DOMParser`, then take the children of the body and `.map` their `.outerHTML`:

```js
const str = '<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure> <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>';

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const arr = [...doc.body.children].map(child => child.outerHTML);
console.log(arr);
```

(you can also achieve this by creating an element and setting the `innerHTML` of the element to the string, and then iterating over its children, but that could allow for arbitrary code execution, if the input string isn't trustworthy)

Answer (score 1):

Dom parsing is recommended.

Here using vanilla JS without the DOMParser used in the other answer

```js
let dataString = `<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure> <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>`;
let domFragment = document.createElement("div");
domFragment.innerHTML = dataString;
const arr = [...domFragment.querySelectorAll("div>p,div>figure")].map(el => el.outerHTML) 
console.log(arr)
```

If you cannot use that, then your **SPECIFIC** string can be split like this after fixing your nested quotes.

Note any change for example adding a space after the `<img..>` will break such a script

```js
let dataString = `<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure> <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>`;
dataString = dataString.replace(/> /g,">|").split("|")
console.log(dataString)
```

Comment: This is very specific to this example. If there is a space after `<img src="" alt="">`, it will add another element in the output

Comment: Hence my statement: _then your SPECIFIC string_

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with your question. Is that a random string or a html string? The split rule is slice the origin string into html element parts?

If true, I think we can handle it with a dummy element.

For convenient, I use jQuery selector:

```js
let stringToSplit = `<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure> <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p> <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>`
$dummy = $("<div/>"); // create a dummy
$dummy.html(stringToSplit);
var dataArray = [];
var dummyChildren = $dummy.children();
for (var i = 0; i < dummyChildren.length; i++) {
  dataArray[i] = dummyChildren[i].outerHTML
}
$dummy = null; // remove from memory
console.log(dataArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet.  You do not actually answer OP's question since you have an array of innerHTML and not outerHTML. Also why loop using a for loop when you have jQuery to your disposal? OP did not actually ask for jQuery either. - also no need to actually append the div to the body. It can be done in memory. See [my version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59353945/295783) which does return the HTML strings requested. Also you do not use `slice` which is a JS function in its own right

Comment: Thank for your tips. I corrected my answer. I'm just a beginner here so my approach may not be the shortest and smartest :D